# kivy scrollview consisting of maplotlib plots not scrolling

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm currently working on building a digital planner app, where I want to include some statistics-related features. Obviously, matplotlib is an optimal means of doing that, but I have two problems with it when I try to add more than one plot in a a Kivy ScrollView:

1. Each plot decreases in size so much that you cannot see what's
   actually being displayed;
2. Kivy ScrollView is not scrolling - unfortunately, very common.

I've tried setting ScrollView's height equal to ScrollView.minimum_height and yet I get no result.

**Here's a bit of my Python code:**

```
class StatsWindow(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    dates_from, dates_to, plot_scroll  = [str(datetime.today()).split()[0]], [str(datetime.today()).split()[0]], ObjectProperty(None)

    def add_sp_plot(self, date_from, date_to):

        # There were too many lines of data handling and plot creating, so I've only left the KivyPart:
        # ------- KIVY part ------- KIVY part ------- KIVY part ------- KIVY part ------- #

        self.plot_scroll.plot_layout.clear_widgets()
        self.plot_scroll.plot_layout.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf(), size_hint_y=None))
        self.plot_scroll.plot_layout.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf(), size_hint_y=None))
        self.plot_scroll.plot_layout.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf(), size_hint_y=None))
```

**Here's a bit of my Kivy code:**

```
<StatsWindow>:
    name: "stats"
    text: "STATS"
    icon: "thumbs-up-down"

    plot_scroll: plot_scroll
    choose_date_to: choose_date_to
    choose_date_from: choose_date_from

    FloatLayout:

        MDLabel:
            halign: "center"
            size_hint: 1, .1
            text: "Choose the dates to view your stats"
            font_size: self.width / 17
            color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint: {"top": .98, "center_x": .5}

        BoxLayout:

            MDFlatButton:
                id: choose_date_from

                pos_hint: {"center_x": .25, "top": .88}

                text: "from"
                size_hint: .4, .1
                font_size: self.width / 11
                on_release: root.open_date_picker(root.dates_from, self)

            MDFlatButton:
                text: "|"
                size_hint: .1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": .88}

            MDFlatButton:
                id: choose_date_to

                font_size: self.width / 11
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .75, "top": .88}

                text: "to"
                size_hint: .4, .1
                font_size: self.width / 11
                on_release: 
                    root.open_date_picker(root.dates_from, self)

        BoxLayout:

            MDFlatButton:
                size_hint: 1, .1
                text: "Load the statistics"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": .78}
                on_release: root.add_sp_plot(choose_date_from.text, choose_date_to.text)

        ScrollView: 
            id: plot_scroll
            do_scroll_y: True
            do_scroll_x: False
            pos_hint: {"top": .68}
            plot_layout: plot_layout
            size: root.width, root.height

            GridLayout:
                id: plot_layout

                cols: 1
                height: self.minimum_height
```

---

[Here's the picture of what I get when I run the program:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0iyv.png)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScrollView` will only scroll if its child (the `GridLayout`) is larger than the `ScrollView`. Also, the line:

```
height: self.minimum_height
```

will have no effect unless you add the line:

```
size_hint_y: None
```

You can increase the size of the plots by specifying a `row_default_height` for the `GridLayout` and eliminating the `size_hint_y=None` for the `FigureCanvasKivyAgg`. So, I would suggest specifying your `ScrollView` as:

```
    ScrollView: 
        id: plot_scroll
        do_scroll_y: True
        do_scroll_x: False
        pos_hint: {"top": .68}
        plot_layout: plot_layout

        GridLayout:
            id: plot_layout
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            row_default_height: 500  # any default row height that you desire
            height: self.minimum_height
```

Then, add the plots using:

```
def add_sp_plot(self, date_from, date_to):

    # There were too many lines of data handling and plot creating, so I've only left the KivyPart:
    # ------- KIVY part ------- KIVY part ------- KIVY part ------- KIVY part ------- #

    self.plot_scroll.plot_layout.clear_widgets()
    self.plot_scroll.plot_layout.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
    self.plot_scroll.plot_layout.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
    self.plot_scroll.plot_layout.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
```

Removing the `size_hint_y=None` leaves the default value of `size_hint_y` as `1`, so that the plot will take up all the space that the `GridLayout` allocates to it (the `row_default_height`).